# Contact Form Leaves Some Fields Blank

Tags: php, html

I have a contact form that I put together and for the most part it works. There are 4 fields that capture the data but there are others that do not post. The name,email,subject,message works fine. Phone, Address, Service Date, and Hear About Us do not post. So my question is do I need to add variable s in my sendmail function. Here is my code. Any input would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

**HTML**

```
 <div class="ten columns">
    <div class="form-div" id="contact-wrap">
      <div id="sucessmessage" class="form-row"> </div>
      <form method="POST" id="ContactForm">
        <div class="span5">
          <label>Full Name:</label>
          <input id="cname" type="text" name="fullname" value="" class="input" />
        </div>
        <div class="span5">
          <label>Your Email:</label>
          <input id="cemail" type="text" name="email" value="" class="input" />
        </div>
        <div class="span5">
          <label>Phone Number:</label>
          <input id="cphone" type="text" name="phone" value="" class="input" />
        </div>
         <div class="span5">
          <label>Address:</label>
          <input id="caddress" type="text" name="address" value="" class="input" />
        </div>
        <div class="span5">
          <label>Subject:</label>
          <input id="csubject" type="text" name="subject" value="" class="input" />
        </div>
         <div class="span5">
          <label>Expected Service Date:</label>
          <input id="cservicedate" type="date" name="servicedate" value="" class="input" />
        </div>
        <div class="span5">
          <label>Office:</label>
          <select name="seloffice" id="seloffice" style="height: 40px;" class="input">
            <option value="">Select Office</option>
            <option value="TEST1a@TEST.com">Mexia Office</option>
            <option value="TEST2@TEST.com" >Ft.Worth Office</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="span5">
          <label>How Did You Hear About Us?</label>
          <select name="hearaboutus" id"hearaboutus" style="height: 40px;" class="input">
            <option value="">Choose One</option>
            <option value="You Contaced Me">You Contacted Me</option>
            <option value="Search Engine" >Search Engine</option>
            <option value="Social Media" >Social Media</option>
            <option value="Advertisement" >Advertisement</option>
            <option value="Friend" >Friend</option>
            <option value="Event" >Event</option>
            <option value="Blog" >Blog</option>
            <option value="Other" >Other</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="span5">
          <label>Message:</label>
          <textarea id="cmsg" name="message" rows="5" cols="10"></textarea>
          <br/>
          <div class="butalign">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submsg" class="but"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 
//echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); echo "<pre>"; die;
if(isset($_POST['fullname']))
{
$name=$_POST['fullname'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
$subject=$_POST['subject'];
$servicedate=$_POST['servicedate'];
$seloffice=$_POST['seloffice'];
$hearaboutus=$_POST['hearaboutus'];
$msg=$_POST['message'];
$message  = "<table border='0' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='1' bgcolor='#cccccc'>
  <tr bgcolor='#ffffff'>
     <td>Name</td>
     <td>".$name."</td>
  </tr>   
  <tr bgcolor='#ffffff'>
     <td>Email</td>
     <td>".$email."</td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor='#ffffff'>
     <td>Phone</td>
     <td>".$phone."</td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor='#ffffff'>
     <td>Address</td>
     <td>".$address."</td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor='#ffffff'>
     <td>Subject</td>
     <td>".$subject."</td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor='#ffffff'>
     <td>Service Date</td>
     <td>".$servicedate."</td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor='#ffffff'>
     <td>Hear About Us</td>
     <td>".$hearaboutus."</td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor='#ffffff'>
     <td>Message</td>
     <td valign='top'>".$msg."</td>
  </tr>
</table>";   

$subject  = "Inquiry/Service Request. -".date("F j, Y");
//$to = "TEST@TEST.com";    
//$Bcc  = "TEST1h@TEST.com";
$from = "Contact Form"; 

//$to = "TESR@TEST.com";    
//$Bcc  = "TEST@TEST.com;
//$from = "TEST@TEST.com";
    $to = $Bcc  = $seloffice;

$headers = "From:" . $email."\n";
$headers .= "Bcc:" . $Bcc."\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$sendMail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
if($sendMail){
  echo "Sucess";
} else {
  echo "Fail";
}}
```

?>

Comment: Done any basic debugging, like `var_dump($_POST)` to see what's really coming through from the form? And generally speaking, you should not be building a mime email manually. use phpmailer or swiftmailer, both of which it trivial to send html email.

Comment: Yes I tried to echo var dump and print r. They both say array empty prior to me submitting. Then when I fill out the form I get the contact form sent message. Im really not sure how to debug the $_POST variable.

Comment: that's to be expected. POST is only populated when you actually submit your form. if your "missing" variables are present in the $_POST dump, but not showing up in your variables, then something is wrong with your php code. if they're not showing up in $_POST at all, then something's wrong with your html.

Comment: I've just tested your form, all the fields are submitted with only doing var_dump($_POST);

Comment: @Spice1, as Marc B said it is the behavior of `$_POST`, Please ask what you don't want your program to do?

Comment: Yes, I am aware that $_POST doesn't display anything until after submission.

Comment: apart from the slapping for not reading right below, you haven't got an action on your form, are they on the same page?

Comment: Yes all on the same page.

Comment: I've added the html and php in one test page and when i enter all data and hit submit everything shows just fine when i echo all posts.

Comment: `echo $name;` `echo '<br />';` `echo $email;` etc. I kept everyting the same from your code. So it's not the code you're showing us that's messing things up for you.

Comment: comment out underneath the table in the php and echo out the table instead of creating the var $message and see if it's ok up to there

Comment: Ok! Wow, not sure where I should look then.

Comment: Maybe you can create a new page and just place HTML and PHP (untill $message) and then echo out everything. You will see it works fine. Somehow some other code interacts with this code and messes things up. How much more code is in the file you are using? And what does it do?

Comment: just having a look at [PHP.net Mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) and quite a few people mention about different behaviour on windows/linux and the \n \r. Which server are you on ?

Comment: Ok so I did check the form and everything seems to be fine. However I just found a JavaScript validation file. I am about to go through it and see if there is anything in there that is causing this issue.